# get rotation from 2d transformation matrix

Tags: matrix, rotation

Assuming I have a 2D rotation matrix:

```
cos(t) -sin(t) 0
sin(t)  cos(t) 0
  0       0    1
```

How do you retrieve the correct rotation angle?

If you use acos on the first element, you only get values between 0 and pi. The question is what do you do if `t` is smaller than 0 (of course I do not know t ;) )?

Comment: Isn't this question supposed on the Math site in stackexchange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `atan2()` in most C-family programming languages takes both a y and x value and computes the arctangent of the ratio between them, taking into account the sign of both terms to give the correct full-circle angle.

`atan2( sin(t), cos(t) )` returns (approximately) `t` in the range (-pi,+pi].

Answer (score 1):

There are an infinite number of `t` that can satisfy the solution (`t + 2*pi()*n`) for integer `n`.  If you use `acos(cos(t))` you'll get the result between 0 and pi, but if you also check `asin(sin(t))` you will be able to figure out whether the rotation was clockwise or counterclockwise.

Comment: can you be more precise? `if(asin(sin(t)) < 0) then degree = -acos(cos(t))` ?

Comment: Let's say t is -0.53.  Remember that cos(t) = cos(-t), so if you use acos(cos(t)) you'll get 0.53.  But if you also check asin(sin(t)), it will return -0.53.  The negative sign tells you the direction of the rotation.  If t were 0.53, both acos(cos(t)) and asin(sin(t)) would return 0.53.